# botão curtir/descurtir com AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

Em uma certa página possuo um botão/link escrito "Favoritar"

```
<a href="SITE.COM/post/favoritar/ID" class="btn-favorite-normal">Favoritar</a>
```

Onde o **ID** é o id da publicação, mas enfim, já possuo um script em PHP que se encarrega de inserir no banco de dados e remover.

quando a publicação é favoritada ou já está marcada como favorita, o script retorna um JSON `{"favorite:1"}` e quando não está marcada como favorita ou a marcação de favorito é removida, o script retorna `{"favorite:0"}`.

apartir desses valores gostaria de alterar o estado do botão com AJAX, por exemplo: ao clicar no botão favoritar, e tudo ocorrer corretamente, o script retornará `{"favorite:1"}` e o nome do botão de "Favoritar" passará a ser "Favoritado", o link(**href**), e a classe de estilo também mudará para, ex:

```
<a href="SITE.COM/post/favoritar/ID/remover" class="btn-favorite-ativo">Favoritado</a>
```

foi adcionado na URL, depois do ID, o nome "remover";
o nome do botão mudou para "favoritado";
e a classe de btn-favorite-normal mudou para btn-favorite-ativo;

o **"remover"** na URL que se encarregará de remover dos favoritos, que ao clicar retornará `{"favorite:0"}` e o botão voltaria ao seu estado normal, escrito "favoritar" e com o link padrão para favoritar.

Comment: O correto é voltar {favorite:0} ou {favorite:1}

Comment: sem as aspas mesmo?

Comment: uhum sem as aspas... qual a sua linguagem de backend? se for php vc pode fazer isso echo json_encode(array('favorite' => 0)); ou então echo json_encode(array('favorite' => 1));

Comment: sim, to usando php, eu tava dando um echo "{favorite:0}", essa função json encode retornou com aspas, {"favorite":1}

Comment: Isso, use da maneira que indiquei:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inicialmente você precisa de um identificador desse botão como vc provavelmente vai ter vários botões como esse vamos usar uma classe.. E vamos colocar um ID para representar o ID real do objeto.
Deixe o link dessa maneira:

`<a href="SITE.COM/post/favoritar/10" id="10" class="btn-favorite-normal favoriteLink">Favoritar</a>`

Agora vamos criar os eventos em JQuery, inicialmente vamos esperar carregar o documento. E em seguida vamos criar as rotinas.

```
<script>
//Espero o DOM ser carregado!
$(function() {
   //Detecto o clique no botão favoriteLink
   $('body').on('click', '.favoriteLink', function () {

       var objClicado = $(this); //Guardo o objeto em uma variavel porque ele não vai ficar disponível dentro do success do ajax.

       // recuperando qual é a url que tá dentro do link
       var url = objClicado.attr('href');
       var id = objClicado.attr('id');
       //Efetuando a chamada AJAX
       $.ajax({
           url : url,
           dataType: 'JSON',
           type: 'GET',
           beforeSend: function () {
              //Aqui vc pode colocar para mostrar alguma coisa enquanto carrega..
              objClicado.addClass("btn-favorite-loading");
           },
           success : function (retorno) {
               objClicado.removeClass("btn-favorite-loading");
               if(retorno.favorite == 1) {
                   objClicado.attr('href', 'SITE.COM/post/favoritar/'+id +'/remover');
                   objClicado.html('Remover');
               } else {
                  objClicado.attr('href', 'SITE.COM/post/favoritar/'+id);
                  objClicado.html('Favoritar');
               }
           },
           error : function (a,b,c) {
                objClicado.removeClass("btn-favorite-loading");
               alert('Erro: '+a['status']+' '+c);
           }
       });

       return false;

   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: As duas condições do if são redundantes por causa do operador "==". Uma só delas já basta.

Comment: Então paulo eu sei que o php faz inclusive eu não tinha colocado, eu escrevi tudo sem testar por isso deixei. Mas tranquilo, === compara tipagem tbm né

Comment: Mas vlw ae!! Editado.

Comment: Tranquilo. :-).

Comment: Ele me retorna um alert com Erro: 0 e depois redireciona pra a página que verifica se é favorito.

Comment: AAAaah me desculpe

Comment: faltou um return false

Comment: O erro 0 ocorre quando é cancelada a requisição ajax, ou seja como eu não dei um return false ele chamou o ajax e redirecionou no redirecionamento ele cancelou mas agora já corrigi o código.

Comment: Ok, irei testar

Comment: Funcionou direitinho, obrigado, é possível colocar algum efeito "loading" enquanto carrega?

Comment: Sou bem leigo em Js, mas na parte do BeforeSend, percebi que o script acessa o "html" do código, acho que o efeito que eu quero é alterar a classe do botão para mudar o estiolo enquanto carrega, algo do tipo class="btn-favorite-loading" .... obrigado

Comment: Pronto alterei o código e coloquei um exemplo de como fazer.. Se possível marca como certa e clica pra dar um ponto ok? Flww :)

Comment: Marquei como resolvido :), eu coloquei o addClass e depois o .html mas não alterou ....

Comment: objClicado.addClass("btn-loading");
objClicado.html("BIRLLLL");

Comment: emite algum erro no console?